# Lirc is conflicted by some default ir-controlling module so that it only sends keyboard input

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, events, lirc

I've tried to find a solution for this problem for some time. Apparently Natty loads some default modules for handling IR-input and sends them as keyboard input instead of the lirc event I want. This makes my remote useless in XBMC (media center program) since I cannot use it for anything else than navigation. A proposed solution is in this bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/766647) but it is regarding a MCE remote and it doesn't work for my Antec Veris rm200. Until the ubuntu-devs make a permanent fix please tell me how to unload all the conflicting modules?

These are the modules which are loaded on my system:

```
lirc_imon
vesafb
nls_iso8859_1
nls_cp437
vfat
fat
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
rt2860sta
arc4
snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep
snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq_midi_event
rt2800pci
rt2800lib
crc_ccitt
ir_lirc_codec
snd_seq
lirc_dev
rt2x00pci
ir_sony_decoder
ir_jvc_decoder
ir_rc6_decoder
snd_timer
snd_seq_device
fglrx
edac_core
rc_imon_pad
rt2x00lib
edac_mce_amd
mac80211
serio_raw
ir_rc5_decoder
imon
ir_nec_decoder
rc_core
k10temp
cfg80211
eeprom_93cx6
snd
vice
sp5100_tco
i2c_piix4
soundcore
snd_page_alloc
xhci_hcd
shpchp
lp
parport
usb_storage
firewire_ohci
firewire_core
usbhid
hid
uas
crc_itu_t
para_jmicron
r8169
ahci
libahci
```

Can anyone help me out? I just want lirc to work correctly which shouldn't be hard. I just need to know which modules to unload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10709651

You need to add this line to /etc/rc.local:

```
echo lirc > /sys/class/rc/rc0/protocols
```

You also might need to add sleep 10 right above that line. Try it without it first and then add it if you need it. I needed it but others didn't.

Comment: Thanks! I will take that as a solution since I no longer have the ability to test it. I added that line earlier but never tried "sleep 10" :)