# How to get my IR remote to work? Lirc can't see it

Tags: 11.10, remote, lirc, dvb

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 (amd64) and I'm trying to get my infrared remote control working.

The IR device is a part of a DVB-T USB stick (Based on a RTL2832u chip). I'm using [these drivers](https://github.com/ambrosa/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0) - it's the only way of getting this device to work under 11.10 that I found. It's a big impromevent from previous Ubuntu version, where I had to edit the driver's code.

The device works quite great - and the IR part of it works, too. The driver's page says that the code it's in alpha stage, but I'm pretty sure that my issue has nothing to do with that.

If, and only if driver's module is loaded with parameter `rtl2832u_rc_mode=2` (which means "use NEC protocol for IR") the remote kind of works, I can see this by running `cat /dev/.. ../input6` - when I press a button, random letters appear. The remote works just like a keyboard, but keys are totally messed up - when I press '5' the volume goes down, etc.

I would like to use **Lirc** to fix that, but Lirc can't detect my device (i.e. `irw` shows nothing). I suspect, it's because something gets into control of the device and sets it up as a keyboard. **Lirc** seems to be working, it's KDE settings module works too, but it just doesn't detect the device.

The Lirc page describes [this issue](http://www.lirc.org/html/devinput.html), but since 2009 - the last year when that page was updated, Ubuntu moved from HAL (described there) to DeviceKit, rendering provided instruction useless.

I had a similar issue with my previous remote, but the keys were not messed up so much - the remote was usable, so I gave up trying to get Lirc working. I tried the answer provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39259/lirc-is-conflicted-by-some-default-ir-controlling-module-so-that-it-only-sends-k), but it changed nothing.

I also tried forcing lircd to use my device, but this didn't work too:

`for i in /sys/class/input/input* ; do echo -n "$(basename "$i"): "; cat "$i/name"; done`

shows

```
input0: Power Button
input1: Power Button
input2: Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
input3: A4Tech PS/2+USB Mouse
input6: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver
```

But when I run:

`lircd -n --device=name='IR*'` as root (also tried with the full name) I always see:

```
lircd-0.9.0[3983]: lircd(default) ready, using /var/run/lirc/lircd
lircd-0.9.0[3983]: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
lircd-0.9.0[3983]: could not get file information for name=IR*
lircd-0.9.0[3983]: default_init(): No such file or directory
lircd-0.9.0[3983]: Failed to initialize hardware
```

So, how to set up Lirc with `devinput` driver in such case?

Comment: Can you post exactly what did you do to make the remote work, i have the same dvb-t chip usb card with no luck around the remote. Tnx, Igor

Comment: @user104159: Make sure that you are forcing rc_mode to 2 (by using module parameter `rtl2832u_rc_mode=2` when loading module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just now solved it.

`lircd -n --device=name='IR*' -H devinput`.

That's it. Works.

Answer (score 1):

Tnx for reply.
I loaded the module with modprobe dvb_usb_rtl2832u rc_mode=2
I have IR-receiver on input4. 
Started lircd with

```
lircd -n --device=name='IR*' -H devinput
```

but no luck with the remote. I also followed  instructions on http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=89669.5;wap2

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -n10 c803
```

gives IR-receiver on event4.
Edited /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
added DRIVER="devinput" and DEVICE=/dev/input/event4

started:

```
irrecord -H dev/input -f -d /dev/input/event4 ~/lircd.conf
```

but no life signs from the remote.
I am using lubuntu 12.04 and Lifeview dvb-t Deluxe usb TV card
Any ideas?

Comment: First, make sure that before you load the module with modprobe it's not loaded (rmmod it if it is). Also, make sure that your remote is physically working. I know it's obvious, but anyone can overlook such things.

Comment: Tnx, i did it. There was a faulty command modprobe dvb_usb_rtl2832u rc_mode=2. I put rtl2832u_rc_mode=2 behind modprobe dvb_usb_rtl2832u, like you said and now it works. Tnx, again, all i need now is to remap keys